# Setting mouse to left handed has no effect in Xubuntu?

Tags: mouse, xubuntu, settings

I'm trying out Xubuntu via the live USB.

I need to set the mouse to be left handed, i.e so when I 'right click', its treated as a left click, and vice versa.

This works fine in Ubuntu, but in Xubuntu, if I go to settings -> Mouse and set it as left handed, it has no effect.

Is this a bug, or only a problem that occurs on the live cd? Should I install or will this problem persist?

Comment: I have a normal Ubuntu install, where I added the XFCE desktop, and I get the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not having this trouble with the live Xubuntu usb. The setting takes effect as soon as soon as I click left-handed. Forgive me for asking, but just to cover all possibilities, are you sure it's not working? Have you tried clicking around?

The setting in *Mouse and Touchpad* can be overridden by settings in *Settings Manager* > *Settings* > *Other* (Scroll to the bottom) > *Settings Editor*

In the *Settings Editor*, choose *Pointers* under the *Channel* pane. You should see your mouse listed. You may have to expand the drop-down arrow, but you should see a Property named *RightHanded* and two check boxes: *Locked* and *Value*. Make sure these are both unchecked.

If this takes care of it for you, keep in mind that the left-handed setting is just for the live environment. You will still need to set the mouse to left-handed after installing.

If this does not take care of it, I wonder if there is a compatibility problem with your mouse. Please edit you question to include to kind of mouse you are usinge

Answer (score 0):

On 14.04, when I go to Settings -> Mouse and Touchpad there are two devices listed.  On for the keyboard and one for the mouse.  I have no idea why the keyboard shows up under the Mouse setting.

Make sure to change the device to your mouse, and then set the settings to use left-handed buttons.

I had the same problem, largely because I didn't read what was listed in the device section (why bother, I only have one mouse...) and so selecting left-handed buttons (for the keyboard) did nothing...